# Drawing Bytes on an Image

Tags: c#, encoding, drawimage

I am trying to get certain bytes to write on an Image, for example:

> " །༉ᵒᵗᵗ͟ᵋༀ  ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟. . . "

When I display it on an image but I am getting the following instead...

*Image*:

[image]

I have tried changing the Encoding Type of the string, when I receive the bytes and there is no set font but I have tried all default Microsoft fonts as well as a few custom ones I found on the Internet. What am I doing Wrong?

---

**Edit**: The original was using `Graphics.DrawString`. I have tried `TextRenderer` and it came out with almost the same results.

*Image*:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxhyU.jpg]

This is the code I'm using to generate the image:

```
string text = "[rotten4pple]  །༉ᵒᵗᵗ͟ᵋༀ  ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟. . .";

var font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
var bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
var size = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap).MeasureString(text, font);
bitmap = new Bitmap((int)size.Width + 4, (int)size.Height + 4);
using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    gfx.Clear(Color.White);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(gfx, cmd.AllArguments, font, new Point(2, 2),
        Color.Black, Color.White);
}
```

The variable `cmd.AllArguments` is passed down into the method, I believe the string is Encoded using `windows-1252`.

Comment: Instead of the literal string, did try using the Unicode codes for them? You can look at Character Map from Windows.

Comment: Well its not just that string though, its any string of like that, the example was just the one im testing with :/

Comment: Even putting the Unicode they won't show? Maybe it's a Culture issue.

Comment: Is this Graphics.DrawString?

Comment: Yes it's using Graphics.DrawString on a Blank image that is CLeared to be white

Comment: Please include the actual code you used to to do both your original test and Theraot's test. We can't tell you what you are doing wrong if you don't show us what you are doing.

Comment: @AlecScratch ... I did the number 11, that converts it to community wiki. That means no more reputations. I did it because edit 8 was actually an step backward, I didn't notice it had reached the edit cap. Coverting this to comunity wiki wasn't my intention, my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

### Imaging

Don't use `Graphics.DrawString` for unicode characters.

You should migrate to `TextRenderer.DrawText` instead, for example:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "こんにちは", this.Font,
            new Point(10, 10), this.ForeColor, this.BackColor, flags);
```

The drawback is that you wont be able to specify a `Brush`.

---

I have tested it. I think some else must be going on, because it seems to work for me. Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var text = " །༉ᵒᵗᵗ͟ᵋༀ  ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟. . . ";
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "TextRenderer.DrawText" + text , this.Font,
        new Point(10, 10), this.ForeColor, this.BackColor);

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Graphics.DrawString" + text, this.Font,
        new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), new PointF(10, 30));
}
```

*Note*: Font is `Arial Unicode MS 8.25pt`.

The output:

[image: text drawing comparison]

---

### Encoding

Here is the original string, stored in UTF-8:

> [rotten4pple] །༉ᵒᵗᵗ͟ᵋༀ  ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟ ͟. . .

And here is the wrong string you are getting, stored in Windows-1252:

> [rotten4pple] à¼à¼‰áµ’áµ—áµ—ÍŸáµ‹à¼€ï£¿ ðŸ¢ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸðŸ¢ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸðŸ› ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸ ÍŸðŸ¢. . .

And they are binary equal. This is the hexadecimal representation of the bytes for both strings:

```
5B 72 6F 74 74 65 6E 34 70 70 6C 65 5D 20 E0 BC
8D E0 BC 89 E1 B5 92 E1 B5 97 E1 B5 97 CD 9F E1
B5 8B E0 BC 80 EF A3 BF 20 F0 9F 90 A2 20 CD 9F
20 CD 9F 20 CD 9F 20 CD 9F 20 CD 9F 20 CD 9F F0
9F 90 A2 20 CD 9F 20 CD 9F 20 CD 9F 20 CD 9F 20
CD 9F 20 CD 9F 20 CD 9F F0 9F 90 9B 20 CD 9F 20
CD 9F 20 CD 9F 20 CD 9F 20 CD 9F 20 CD 9F F0 9F
90 A2 2E 20 2E 20 2E
```

Since this is a re-interpretation of the binary values and not a re-encoding, converting from one to the other with `Encoding.Convert` in .NET is not viable. Instead you should get the binary representation of the string in the wrong encoding and read it as the correct encoding directly:

```
var text = cmd.AllArguments;
var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(text);
text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

**Notes**

You have been asking for what encoding uses the API you are using by default. I'm not familiar with the API you are using... yet, there is risk that it depends on the configuration of the machine. You should look for an overload that allows you to specify that you are receiving an UTF-8 string.

The chances are that you are actually receiving a `byte[]` anyway, so you can use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` directly on it. If you cannot specify the encoding, you should consider switching to send `byte[]` instead, the purpose of this is to have more control over the encoding.

On that regard, don't use `Encoding.Default` because it will be Extended ASCII for the language of the machine.

By the way, UTF-8 is a good choice for networking, not only because it is independent of the language and other regional configuration, but also because it is independent of byte order (endianness).

Comment: I tried this and it still came out with the incorrect Characters :/

Comment: what encoding would the string have as default? I'm getting all the strings from a Async TCP based chat client, I don't know if that will help at all towards a solution

Comment: @AlecScratch as far as I know, you should send the string as a byte[], on the other side you recive this byte[] and convert it to string. When converting the string to byte[] and viceversa you should take the encoding into account. If you are converting and you don't know the encoding, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I know what encoding I'm using, but what is the default encoding for a string? I'm using Windows-1252.

Comment: @AlecScratch I have discovered the encoding problem and solved it, see update.

Comment: Thanks alot! This worked wonders! Yeah I found that I was reading the bytes from the TCP stream as 1252, right after I found this, so i switched it to UTF8, thanks again, you were a big help!